# Why is the error callback in this ajax call is getting executed alternatively

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following piece of JQuery code which makes an ajax call every 20 seconds.

```
var uiBlocked = false;
var timerCount = 20;
window.setInterval(function() {
 $.ajax({
   cache: false,
   type: 'HEAD',
   url: '/heartbeat/',
   timeout: 1000,
   async: true,
   success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    if (uiBlocked == true && navigator.onLine) {
       uiBlocked = false;
       $.unblockUI();
      }
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    if(textStatus != 'timeout'){
      if (uiBlocked == false){
          uiBlocked = true;
          alert(textStatus);
          $.blockUI({
            message: 'Lost connectivity, please reconnect your VPN.<br/>Retrying in <span  id="timer">20</span> .... secs.',
            css: {
             border: 'none',
             padding: '15px',
             backgroundColor: '#000',
             '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
             '- moz-border-radius': '10px',
             opacity: .5,
             color: '#fff'
           },
           onBlock: function counterFunction() {
               document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML= timerCount;
               timerCount--;
               if(timerCount >= 0){
                  setTimeout(counterFunction, 1000);
               }
               else{
                  timerCount = 20;
                  uiBlocked = false;
               }
           }
        });
      }
    }
  }
 })
}, 20000);
```

Inside my error part I call the setTimeout function to decrement the counter. The counter decrements and alert is executed and counter resets to 20 seconds. But upon the second call the error callback does not get executed. This again gets executed on the third call.

Is my timer somewhere going wrong . Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Ok so this works correctly if I remove the uiBlock flag.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the quirky behavior of timers and intervals and the fact that JS is single threaded.

Its by no means a solution but i would recommend checking out this great post by John Resig -  aka Mr jQuery.

[How JavaScript Timers Work](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/)

I have the JS Ninja Book he authored and it has a similar chapter, was a real eye opener for me how these operators behave.

Comment: I think the timer is working fine as another heartbeat call gets made when the counter becomes zero, the part that is confusing is why the error callback does not get executed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need `setInterval` instead of recursive `setTimeout` in your problem.

Here I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/765zmh8d/1/) to simplify your problem so that it's easier to understand:

```
$(function(){
   var i = 20,
       interval;

    $('#button').click(function(){
        i = 20;

        if (interval){
            clearInterval(interval)
        }

        interval = setInterval(function(){
            if (i >= 0){
                $('#counter').text(i--);
            } else {
                clearInterval(interval) 
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

As you can see, it is very important to reset the `i` variable (the `timerCount` in your example) as well as doing `clearInterval()` on previously declared `setInterval()`

Update:

In your case

```
var timer;
// ....

onBlock: function counterFunction() {
    timerCount = 20;
    if (iterval) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (timerCount >= 0) {
            $('#timer').text(--timerCount);
        } else {
            clearInterval(interval);
            uiBlocked = false;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: If I do a setInterval the timer counter does not work correctly.

Comment: I adapted your code so it uses setInterval() in the answer (after "Update:"), does it work for you?

Comment: I don't know how but if I removed the uiBlocked flag it works fine

Comment: You mean all occurrences of uiBlocked or just ones in counterFunction function ?

Comment: All occurrences of uiBlocked flag